# How to avoid a ValueError unpacking tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I have a list of tuples that look like this:

```
('"FoxNews"', '"BREAKING: Federal appeals court rules against Trump administration on DACA"', 'tbd')
```

And am trying to run the following code:

```
Scored_NS = []
for (username, words, sentiment) in News_Sample:
...     if type(words) is list:
...         username =username
...         words_scored = [t.lower() for t in words if len(t) >= 3]
...         sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words))
...     else:
...         username = username
...         words_scored = [t.lower() for t in words.split() if len(t) >= 3]
...         sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words.split()))
...     Scored_NS.append((username, words_scored, sentiment))
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

This is the output I am looking for:

```
('"FoxNews"', '"BREAKING: Federal appeals court rules against Trump administration on DACA"', 'neg')
```

Basically the code is replacing the 'tbd' with a 'pos' or 'neg' tag for some sentiment analysis I am doing. Any ideas why this is happening? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong because this code:

```
test_sample = []
for (words, sentiment) in test_tweets:
    if type(words) is list:
        words_filtered = [t.lower() for t in words if len(t) >= 3]
        sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words))
    else:
        words_filtered = [t.lower() for t in words.split() if len(t) >= 3]
        sentiment = classifier.classify(extract_features(words.split()))
    test_sample.append((words_filtered, sentiment))
```

Worked when the tuple looked like this:

```
('"BREAKING: Federal appeals court rules against Trump administration on DACA"', 'tbd')
```

Giving the following output:

```
('"BREAKING: Federal appeals court rules against Trump administration on DACA"', 'neg')
```

Here are is a sample of what `News_Sample` looks like:

```
[('"FoxNews"', '"BREAKING: Federal appeals court rules against Trump administration on DACA"', 'tbd'), ('"FoxNews"', '"Breaking News: Grand jury indicts captain of Missouri duck boat that sank in severe weather, killing 17 people"', 'tbd'), ('"FoxNews"', '"JUST IN: Police identify gunman who opened fire inside California bar, killing 12"', 'tbd'), ('"FoxNews"', '"JUST IN: Supreme Court Justice Ruth Bader Ginsburg fractures 3 ribs in fall"', 'tbd')]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have one or many tuple in `News_Sample` that is of size two. My advice would be to iterate through that list and stop if you have only two element in the list.
That message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
`
Is saying exactly that.

Comment: `News_Sample` is not defined. You need to make a [mre]. We can't give a definitive answer until you do, but @Yacine is probably right. Also on that note, the `for`-block is irrelevant. You might as well replace it with `pass`.

Comment: Just an observation:

`words_scored = [t.lower for t in words.split() if len(t) >= 3]`

Both lines 4 and 7 have that as t.lower instead of t.lower()

Comment: It appears the some of the tuples in `News_Sample` consist of only two values, do you know why that is and how you want to handle them?

Comment: @martineau thank you for the observation. The issue was that the first line of 'News_Sample' was my header with only two values. I removed it and the code worked fine.